# Exclude certain relationships from cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm looking to make a cypher query which finds all outgoing relationships from node, excluding a couple. Here's an example:

```
START node=node(5), excludeRels=rel(7,8,9)
MATCH node-[rels]->x
RETURN rels
```

But I would like to exclude the rels in `excludeRels` from the returned `rels`. So if `node(5)` has outgoing relationships 6,7,8,9 and 10, I would like 6 and 10 to be returned.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the `rel(7,8,9)` doing? I couldn't find any infos about `rel()` except for the use case `rel(path)` where it returns a collection of the relationships of `path`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incase anyone else is wondering, I found the answer to the above problem to be:

```
START node=node(5), excludeRels=rel(7,8,9)
WITH node, collect(excludeRels) as erels
MATCH node-[rel]->()
WHERE NOT rel IN erels
RETURN rel
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work

```
START node=node(5), excludeRels=rel(7,8,9)
MATCH node-[rel]->()
WHERE rel <> excludeRels
RETURN rel
```